# Change color of table cell previous to select dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Choose</th>
     <td>
          <select name='choose' class='dropdown'>
                <option value='1'>1</option>
                <option value='1'>1</option>
                <option value='1'>1</option>
          </select>
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

When dropdown changes, i would like to add a class to the previous th

```
$('.dropdown').change(function(){
            $(this).closest('th').addClass('done');
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$('.dropdown').change(function(){
            $(this).prev('th').addClass('done');
});
```

This is not adding the class as i hoped. thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest) to get the closest `td` ancestor and use [`prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) on it.

```
$('.dropdown').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('td').prev('th').addClass('done');
    //      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9zdvf2L9/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get to the parent td before referencing previous th.

```
 $(this).closest('td').prev('th').addClass('done');
```

or

```
 $(this).parent().prev().addClass('done');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the parent elements previous sibling

```
$('.dropdown').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().prev('th').addClass('done');
});
```

Comment: is there any benefits to using parent or closest('td')

Comment: @bart2puck if you are sure about the parent/child relationship .parent() should be faster